# Python - import mysql - IDLE/works VisualStudio/dosn't work

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-code

Simple code, which I use to study python. The code work in the default editor IDLE from python installation, but in Visual Studi Code doesn't work. I have instaled mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python...

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

def connect():
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='test', user='root', password='*******')
        if conn.is_connected():
            print('Connected to MySql database')
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        conn.close()
connect()
```

[IDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnidW.png)
[VISUAL STUDIO CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGb7E.png)

```
Installed packages
C:\mp>pip list
Package                  Version
------------------------ -------
cachetools               4.0.0
dnspython                1.16.0
google-api-python-client 1.7.11
google-auth              1.10.2
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.3
httplib2                 0.16.0
mypy                     0.761
mypy-extensions          0.4.3
**mysql                    0.0.2
mysql-connector          2.2.9
mysql-connector-python   8.0.19
mysqlclient              1.4.6**
oauth2client             4.1.3
pip                      20.0.1
protobuf                 3.6.1
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
PyDrive                  1.3.1
PyYAML                   5.3
rsa                      4.0
setuptools               41.2.0
six                      1.14.0
typed-ast                1.4.1
typing-extensions        3.7.4.1
uritemplate              3.0.1
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not telling us the exact error message?

Comment: could you be using the wrong python environment in Visual Studio Code? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: error is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/mp/mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "c:\mp\mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package

Comment: python environment: is python.exe, IDLE use pythonW.exe, but when I start the code with pythonW the script doesn't work again, only work in IDLE

Comment: The problem was that my code file name was mysql.py. Interpreter try to import the same file... which is not possible. Just need to change the name of the file with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the name of the file which contained the code in Visual Studio code.

I try to "import mysql" and the name of the file which contains the main training code is mysql.py

After the change of name was done(mysql.py > mysqltest.py), the code begins to work. 
That means when you try to import something in your program, python first checks the folder of the programs and after that the PAHT of libraries.